Using LM324 to stabilize the DAC output in the 0-10 V range


I'm designing a hobby project where I'm communicating analog data via a PLC. I want to convert the output of my MCU's DAC to a 0-10V signal using a noninverting opamp. I'm controlling the gain of the opamp with a potentiometer.
I have an issue in that the output voltage is either 0V or 10V, and I can't seem to get it to scale smoothly in between. Here's the setup:

DAC output: An analog output from the MCU (0-3.3V or 0-5V.)
Opamp configuration: Noninverting amplifier.
Potentiometer: The gain is adjustable via a potentiometer (10K.)

The opamp is properly powered, but the output voltage only reaches the extreme values (0V or 10V.) When I adjust the gain potentiometer, the output doesn't seem to change smoothly within the desired range (e.g., 0-10V.)
What could be causing this? How can I modify the circuit to achieve a proper 0-10V output range?

What is the supply voltage for the opamp?

Welcome! Stabilize is a strange word here. Most people would call it buffer. Regarding your layout, when you bridge pins like that, some EMSes complain that they can't differentiate between shorted pins and intended shorted pins by AOI. If you want to avoid this if this project goes from hobby to a commercial one, make a small loop in the form of a C to connect them. Please look up how a non-inverting amplifier opamp is connected and then simulate your circuit to build your understanding.

Can you confirm that the DAC output is changing as expected? Is it a true DAC or some PWM thing? Also check polarity of input. Negative inputs to the non-inverting pin would cause the output to change from ~0V to almost 12V at around -600mV (more negative voltages would be clamped).

@Tyassin The printed wiring shows +12V and GND are powering the LM324 op amp.

Yes of course, should have noticed.

The circuit I designed is a simple non-inverting op-amp circuit, and I based the design on the datasheet reference design. The op-amp can operate with a maximum supply voltage of 30V, but I am providing it with a 12V DC supply. The DAC output comes from the STM32 DAC output. When I simulated the circuit in LTSpice, it worked successfully as expected. However, I am wondering if there could be any issues with the PCB design.

You might want to read the Design Guidelines for the LM324 particularly wrt. unused inputs. They should be grounded via a resistor.

First probe the MCU DAC output with the multimeter. Do you get the DAC output you want, or is it jumping between 0V and 3V3? There's also the issue of the 3 unused opamps having the input connected to the supply. That violates the allowed input common mode range. I don't know if that will upset the opamp you're using, though. The four opamps do use a common bias circuit, so that's a possibility.

@bobflux When I tested the DAC output with a multimeter, I could see the desired values correctly. However, I believe there is an issue related to the CubeIDE version I am using. While the automatically generated code does not make the DAC function properly, the DAC peripheral produces the expected values when I use code written at the register level. Despite this, the noninverting op-amp circuit is still not functioning correctly.

There are no GND vias in the layout picture. Is it possible, that the LM324 has no true GND connection?

The op-amp has 12VDC and 0VDC connections. When testing with a multimeter, I am able to confirm all the necessary power connections.

Please provide a single setup set of measurements as follows: Input about 1V. Pot about midscale Measure the voltage at the chip  pin 5, 6, 7  relative to pin 10. Confirm 4 at 12V. I don't think the 12V on inputs is causing your problem, though it's not ideal - it's pretty much what happens when you leave the inputs open- TI now recommends no input connected directly to GND whether GND is pin 10 or not.

The recommended operating conditions in the TI data sheet clearly state that inputs should not be any closer to the positive rail than 2 volts: -

You say in comments that your supply rail is +12 volts but, you have three of the four op-amps connected to +12 volts via their non-inverting inputs. OK you could say that the three op-amps in question are unused but, they are all on the same silicon die and they will share circuit resources so, my advice to you is connect those three non-inverting inputs to 0 volts (permitted).

I cannot implement the mentioned setup on the PCB because it would require damaging the traces. Instead, I will route the necessary connections externally and test them on a separate breadboard. For the unused op-amp circuits, I plan to configure them as simple buffer circuits by connecting the positive inputs to GND and the negative inputs to the output.

@jonif17 "damaging the traces" is normally called patching when prototyping.

I can't say for sure that this 12V in will case the 324 to misbehave,  it's blind above about VCC-2V, but I can't see this injecting problems.

Find the required gain for the two possible input ranges:
$$ A_3 = \frac{+10V}{+3.3V} = 3.0 $$
$$ A_5 = \frac{+10V}{+5.0V} = 2.0 $$
You'll want to adjust gain slightly beyond those values, say \$1.8 < A < 3.2\$. The amplifier will be non-inverting, with this arrangement of feedback resistances R1 and R2:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Gain \$A\$ is:
$$ A = 1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} $$
If we keep R1 fixed at 10kΩ, we must calculate what range of values of R2 will correspond to \$A=1.8\$ and \$A=3.2\$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= 1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} \\ \\
R_2 &= \frac{R_1}{A-1} \\ \\
R_{2(MIN)} &= \frac{R_1}{A_3-1} = \frac{10k\Omega}{3.2-1} = 4.5k\Omega \\ \\
R_{2(MAX)} &= \frac{R_1}{A_5-1} = \frac{10k\Omega}{1.8-1} = 12.5k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
R2 can be made adjustable between 4.5kΩ and 12.5kΩ by replacing it with a fixed 4.5kΩ resistance in series with a variable 8kΩ resistance:

simulate this circuit
The hardest part to obtain will be the 8kΩ potentiometer. 10kΩ would be easy, though, and happens to be what you already have, so let's use that. If we scale all the resistances by the same amount, gain doesn't change, so let's find the scaling factor \$K\$:
$$ K = \frac{10k}{8k} = 1.25 $$
Scale all the resistances by the same factor:
$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1 &= 10k\Omega \times K \approx 12k\Omega \\ \\
R_3 &= 8k\Omega \times K \approx 10k\Omega \\ \\
R_4 &= 4.5k\Omega \times K \approx 5.6k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
With a negative supply of 0V, your op-amp can't output 0V. You should not expect under +50mV. This means that you'll need to aim for an output starting at about +50mV, for which we will need to raise input potential very slightly. This can be done with a resistor potential divider:

simulate this circuit
I didn't do any algebra for this, I just used the simulator to adjust R5 and R6 until I got \$V_X \approx +25mV\$ when \$V_{IN}=0V\$. I know this will be multiplied by about 2 or more, producing an output offset of at least +50mV. The ratio of resistance is so large that attenuation is correspondingly small, and can be compensated for by adjusting gain with R3. Importantly, input impedance remains very high, so the DAC isn't loaded excessively.
The final circuit is:

simulate this circuit
With potentiometer R3 set near 4% of its maximum resistance (about 400Ω), gain is near maximum, and the output goes from around +50mV to +10V, as the input is swept from 0V to +3.3V:

